# Selecting a HTML tag wih JS before the specific tag has been closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, getelementsbytagname, onscroll

I'd like to understand why I can't seem to be able to attach the onscroll to the variable containing the DOM element .

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var vbody = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    vbody.onscroll = function() {
      console.log('scrolling');
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code logs nothing. However, if you just change the

```
vbody.onscroll
```

to

```
window.onscroll
```

console logs "scrolling" when you, well, scroll - just like it should.

What am I doing wrong? I'd like add an onscroll event handler to the body element and have it function like when using window.onscroll in the example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code gives you a HTMLCollection.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body');
```

You need to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var vbody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  vbody.onscroll = function() {
    console.log('scrolling');
  }
});
```

Or since you are using jQuery, stick with it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").scroll(function() {
    console.log('scrolling');
  });
});
```

Comment: An even easier way to get the plain body element would be by getting `document.body`, instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp Nice... Yes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `var vbody = document.getElementsByTagName('body');`

to  `var vbody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];`

You need to add at the end [0] because  `document.getElementsByTagName('body')` returns an array and you need single instance of body.

Comment: A `HTMLCollection` not an array! :)